# Couldnot create a coupon code programmatically

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, enterprise-library

I am creating coupon code(shopping cart rule) programmatically in Magento Enterprise ver. 1.12.0.2.

Coupon code gets created without any problem.

But when I add the condition with the third rule i.e "1--1--1" as shown below and execute it, It gives error as

*"Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`dbname`.`salesrule_product_attribute`, CONSTRAINT `FK_SALESRULE_PRODUCT_ATTRIBUTE_RULE_ID_SALESRULE_RULE_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`rule_id`) REFERENCES `salesrule` (`rule_id`) ON DELETE C)' in D:\wamp\www\projectname\lib\Zend\Db\Statement\Pdo.php".*

My code for condition is as shown below:

```
  $conditions = array(
        "1" => array(
            'type' => 'salesrule/rule_condition_combine',
            'aggregator' => 'all',
            'value' => 1,
            'new_child' => false
            ),
        "1--1" => array(
            'type' => 'salesrule/rule_condition_product_found',
            'value' => 1,
            'aggregator' => 'all',
            'new_child' => false
        ),
        "1--1--1" => array(
            'type' => 'salesrule/rule_condition_product',
            'attribute' => "category_ids",
            'operator' => "!=",
            'value' => "10"
        )
    );
$rule = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule');
....
...
$rule->setData('conditions',$conditions);
$rule->loadPost($rule->getData());
$rule->save();
```

Can anyone help on this?

Comment: see this: http://marius-strajeru.blogspot.com/2010/04/create-bulk-discount-rules.html, Maybe it helps

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using it, I believe that disabling the Enterprise Rewards module can sometimes fix this PDO exception error. Try following [this guide](https://support.sweettoothrewards.com/entries/21508947-How-To-Disable-The-Default-Magento-Enterprise-Rewards-Module) and see if it fixes your issue.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not very familiar with Magento, I've just come across a similar issue somewhere else and thought I'd suggest the solution incase it happened to solve your problem. Best of luck, hope you get it sorted!